# NSOutputStream cannot be closed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking

Here is the issue. When my app starts up, I connect to server1 at port 5000. I send to data to server1. Server1 sends data back. Server1 close connection. NSStreamEventEndEncountered event occurs for inputStream. Then I connect to server2 at port 5001. I try to send data to server2, but the data ends up going to server1. Somehow the inputStream is connected at port 5001 and my outputStream isconnected at 5000. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication: (uint32_t)port {
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", port, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}

- (void) onClientConnectionLost {
    if (atServer1 == YES) {
        atServer1 = NO;
        [self initNetworkCommunication: 5001];
    }
    if (atServer1 == NO) {
        atServer1 = YES;
        [self initNetworkCommunication: 5000];
    }
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
    switch (streamEvent) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:            
            if (theStream == inputStream) {
                //handle packets...             
            }
            break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            if (theStream == inputStream) {
                [theStream close];
                [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
                [theStream release];
                theStream = nil;

                [outputStream close];
                [outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
                [outputStream release];
                outputStream = nil;

                [self onClientConnectionLost];            
            }
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void) onClientConnectionLost {
if (atServer1 == YES) {
    atServer1 = NO;
    [self initNetworkCommunication: 5001];
}
else if (atServer1 == NO) {
    atServer1 = YES;
    [self initNetworkCommunication: 5000];
}
```

}

On your old code... when atServer1 = YES, it will execute the first if statement.... which sets atServer1 to NO... so second if statement is TRUE.. so it will also executes that..